# Can you please help me to understand this failed transaction?

Tags: error

Good day,

I am learning.  Can someone help me to understand what happened and went wrong here: https://etherscan.io/tx/0xff8066ef6f01979d18829b1b0f744918018f9ca61d6d1a2f3c1446d3e4885311

I assume the ETH gas is gone too?  I would like to avoid this mistake/error in the future.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

From [the documentation](https://docs.uniswap.org/protocol/reference/periphery/libraries/TransferHelper#safetransferfrom):

> Transfers tokens from the targeted address to the given destination Errors with '**STF**' if transfer fails

STF stands for safeTransferFrom. So there is an error when transferring the tokens. It is likely you didn't execute the `approve()` function before doing the swap. Or you didn't `approve()` enough of the token you are trying to swap.